# Swift 3 - No 'sort' candidates produce the expected contextual result type 'NSMutableArray'

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, sorting, nsmutablearray

I am attempting to sort a mutable array in Swift 3.1.1, but get the same error every time:
No 'sort' candidates produce the expected contextual result type 'NSMutableArray'.
Is there a way to sort a mutable array (Ints only) in ascending order?

In my code, elements from options are being removed. Removed (the array) is adding the removed elements. At the end of the code I am attempting to add the elements from the removed array back to options and sort it.

```
// set up tiles
var options = NSMutableArray()
var removed = NSMutableArray()
for i in 1...49 {
    options.add(i as Int)
    print("options\(options.count)")
}
for i in 1...49 {
    print("i = \(i)")
    options.remove(i)

    let tilea: Int = options[Int(arc4random_uniform(UInt32(options.count)))] as! Int
    options.remove(tilea)
    let tileb: Int = options[Int(arc4random_uniform(UInt32(options.count)))] as! Int
    options.remove(tileb)
    removed.add([i, tilea, tileb])
    print(options.count)

    if options.count < 20 {
        options.add(removed)
         options = options.sort {
             $0 < $1
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: `NSMutableArray` is Obj-C, while `sort` is only for Swift Array I suppose, change your `NSMutableArray()` to `[Int]()`

Comment: This algorithm is written in a reallllllly sketchy way. I suggest you better explain what you're trying to achieve, so we can find a better solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As already mentioned, in Swift you should really be using the [`Array<T>`](http://swiftdoc.org/v3.1/type/Array/) for this (aka, `[T]`) instead of `NSMutableArray`. For instance:

```
var options = [Int]()
```

when adding elements to it, use `append` (and, by the way, you can drop the *type cast* as well):

```
options.append(i)
options.append(contentsOf: [i, j, k])
```

finally, when *sorting* the array, use the `sort` function (it doesn't return a value; the array is sorted in-place):

```
options.sort()
```

and you don't need even to provide a *comparation function* since integers conform to the `Comparable` protocol.

Answer (score 2):

`NSMutableArray`, among other Objective C types, was implicitly bridged to/from its Swift counterparts. In a move to lessen peoples (usually unnecessary) reliance on these Objective C types, this implicit bridging has been changed in Swift 3, and now needs an explicit type coercion (e.g `nsArray as [Int]`)

Comment: Nice insight, I didn't know that :) BTW, I think you meant an *explicit* type coercion, right?

Comment: @PauloMattos Yep, my mistake :p